# Criando um Uber Jar com Gradle não está funcionando

Tags: java, gradle

Estou usando o plugin do [johnrengelman
/
shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) para criar um [uber jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947037/what-is-an-uber-jar) com as algumas dependências locais, mas por alguma razão que desconheço não está funcionando.

build.gradle

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:5.2.0'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '5.2.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = 'https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/'
    }

    maven {
        url = 'https://repo.bukkit.org/content/groups/public/'
    }

    maven {
        url = 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2'
    }
}

shadowJar {
   archiveBaseName = "uber"
   classifier = ''
   archiveVersion = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: 'minecraft-colors-*.jar')
    shadow fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: 'knautiluz-http-*.jar')
    shadow fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: 'knautiluz-http-services-*.jar')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.8.1'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'
    compileOnly 'org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.15.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

group = 'com.knautiluz.lorelei'
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
description = 'Knautiluz Verify'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from(components.java)
        }
    }
}
```

Com os comandos `gradle build` e `gradle shadowJar` os jars criados são praticamente os mesmos, e não carregam as dependências mencionadas
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apesar de ver em diversos locais que a forma de criar o shade é usar o `shadow` algo deve ter mudado na ultima versão, pois obtive o uber jar usando `implementation` no lugar do `shadow` ficando:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: 'minecraft-colors-*.jar')
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: 'knautiluz-http-*.jar')
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: 'knautiluz-http-services-*.jar')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.8.1'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'
    compileOnly 'org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.15.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E assim ele criou meu jar gordinho com as dependências.